# Kendo UI (multiSelect) - OnClick show selected values and clear the values

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, dojo, kendo-multiselect

I am using Kendo UI - MultiSelect Dropdown for selectbox replace...

OnClick of link, how can I show **selected values**? Once I show it, I have to **clear the values** in KendoSelect to default placeholder (`--- Select ---`)....

> **[Online Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ecARa/2)**

**HTML**

```
<select class="mySelectBox" data-placeholder="--- Select ---" multiple="multiple">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
  <option>Option 4</option>
  <option>Option 5</option>
</select>

<div><a href="#" id="showSelectedValues">Show Selected Values</a></div>

<h5>Values are: <span></span></h5>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".mySelectBox").kendoMultiSelect({
    placeholder: "--- Select ---",
  });

  $("#showSelectedValues").click(function(){
    var selVals = $(".mySelectBox").data("kendoMultiSelect").value([]);
    $("h5 span").html(selVals);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully this is what you are looking for:

[Select Dropdown Values and then reset afterwards](http://dojo.telerik.com/AsodE/2)

I have tweaked your javascript for you slightly to:

```
 $("#showSelectedValues").click(function(){
    var selVals = $("select.mySelectBox").data("kendoMultiSelect");
    $("h5 span").html('<code>' + selVals.value($("#value").val()) + '</code>');

    selVals.value(null);

  });
```

then I am simply wrapping the values in a code block for you. But you can show them how you want.

Comment: **@David Shorthose**.. Thanks.. working as expected... Keep up the Good Work

Answer (score 3):

Do not use jquery selector by class: `$(".mySelectBox").data("kendoMultiSelect")`, because kendo apply that class also to `<div>` that wrap `<select>`.
Use `id` attribute instead:

```
<select id="mySelectBox"...
```

and javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mySelectBox").kendoMultiSelect({
    placeholder: "--- Select ---",
  });
  $("#showSelectedValues").click(function(){
    var multiselect = $("#mySelectBox").data("kendoMultiSelect");
    $("h5 span").html(multiselect.value().join());
    multiselect.value([]);
  });
});
```

Comment: **@Gene R**... Thanks for the TIP